How can I check the balance of a 10 year old wallet that can't sync?
I have a very old PC that blue screens every time I try to sync bitcoin core and I was wondering if there was any way I could check the balance of the wallet before I destroy the PC?

It has 10~ receiving addresses and they all seem to have 0 balance on cointracker.io and blockchain.com/explorer/
I've think I've also extracted the public and private keys but I'm not sure what to do next
Presumably if all of the receiving addresses are showing 0 balance then there is no point pursuing this?
I am a bit tentative especially as when I check my Ledger wallet and receiving addresses, they also appear as 0 balance on these sites even though I have more than 0 balance

Alternatively, you can export all private keys, copy them to a new computer, install Electrum (a lightweight wallet which doesn't need to download the full blockchain), create a new wallet using the private keys and check the balance.


How can I check the balance of a 10 year old wallet that can't sync?

I would

Use the backup option in the wallet software.

Copy the backup file to a new computer.

Install the latest Bitcoin core on the new computer.

Restore the wallet from the backup file on the new computer.


